# I'm doing a tutorial in python 2.7.8 and keep getting an error for the first flag

Tags: python

I'm doing a tutorial in python 2.7.8 and keep getting an error for the first flag usage. is there a better way to write this and why is it not working? I ran into some problems getting 3.0 to work with missing Parentheses, as Python no longer allows Print "hello World" it has to be print ("hello") like in Java. But the I can't see how the code bellow will not run. Please help or direct me to a better tutorial.

```
import wx


app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple Editor', size=(450, 350))

bkg = wx.panel(frame)

loadButton = bkg = wx.Button(bkg, label="Open")
saveButton = wx.Button(bkg, label='Save')
filename = wx.TextCtrl(bkg)
contents = wx.TextCtrl(bkg, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)

hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
hbox.Add(filename, proportion=1. flag=wx.EXPAND)
hbox.Add(loadButton, proportion=0. flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)
hbox.Add(saveButton, proportion=0. flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)

vbox = BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
vbox.Add(hbox, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
vbox.Add(contents, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.BUTTON | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

bkg.SetSizer(vbox)


frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of the error; I have *no idea* what you mean by *an error for the first flag usage*.

Answer (score 1):

```
proportion=1.
```

This should have a comma, not a period.

```
proportion=1,
```

You're getting an error at `flag=wx.EXPAND` because that immediately follows, and isn't expected to be after a number (which `1.` is).

Same for the next 2 lines as well.